# Why can't I access React Context variables and states changes inside onClick function of a button in a custom Autodesk extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autodesk-forge, react-context, autodesk-viewer

I Have a Viewer component which uses context variables and works fine. I want to implement some custom extensions to this viewer, and I placed their declaration inside useEffect hook running just once, they're being registered.

Inside these extensions I have some buttons, that are loaded in `onToolbarCreated`, and onClick function uses React Context variables but they return undefined or the initial value, how to make them recognize these variables?

Code:

```
function Viewer() {
const {
    setMainViewer,
    isTreeActive,
    isIssuesListActive,
    isBlueprintsListActive,
    isIssueDatailsActive,
    setCurrentIssueSelected,
    currentIssueSelected,
} = useContext(AppContext);

useEffect(() => {
    const auxinitViewer = async () => {
        setMainViewer(
            await initViewer(document.getElementById("mainViewerDiv"))
        );
    };
    initExtensions();
    auxinitViewer();
}, []);

const initExtensions = async () => {

    // TOOLBAR EXTENSION
    function UpperViewPanel(viewer, options) {
        //... code
    }

    UpperViewPanel.prototype = Object.create(
        Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel.prototype
    );
    UpperViewPanel.prototype.constructor = UpperViewPanel;

    function ToolbarExtension(viewer, options) {
        Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
    }

    ToolbarExtension.prototype = Object.create(
        Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype
    );
    ToolbarExtension.prototype.constructor = ToolbarExtension;

    ToolbarExtension.prototype.load = function () {
        this.viewer.fitToView();
        return true;
    };

    ToolbarExtension.prototype.unload = function () {
        if (this.subToolbar) {
            this.viewer.toolbar.removeControl(this.subToolbar);
            this.subToolbar = null;
        }
    };
    var button3 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button("enable-upper-view");

    ToolbarExtension.prototype.onToolbarCreated = async function (toolbar) {
        var mainViewer = this.viewer;
        const upper_view_panel_div =
            document.getElementById("upper-view-panel");
        if (upper_view_panel_div) {
            upper_view_panel_div.remove();
        }
        
        let panel;
        if (mainViewer.model.is3d()) {
            panel = new UpperViewPanel(this.viewer, null);
            panel.initViewer();
        }

        button3.onClick = function (e) {
            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM, currentIssueSelected is always undefined
            console.log("CURRENT ISSUE SELECTED", currentIssueSelected);
            if (!currentIssueSelected) {
                showErrorToasty(
                    "Não é possível ver planta sem um problema selecionado"
                );
            } else {
                if (!currentIssueSelected.linkedDocuments[0]) {
                    showErrorToasty(
                        "Este problema não contém posicionamento"
                    );
                } else {
                    if (
                        panel.getVisibility().display === "block" &&
                        panel.getVisibility().zIndex === "-1"
                    ) {
                        panel.setIssue(currentIssueSelected);
                        panel.setVisible();
                        button3.removeClass("top_view");
                        button3.addClass("top_view_selected");
                    } else if (panel.getVisibility().display === "none") {
                        panel.setIssue(currentIssueSelected);
                        panel.setVisible();
                        button3.removeClass("top_view");
                        button3.addClass("top_view_selected");
                    } else if (
                        panel.getVisibility().display === "block" &&
                        panel.getVisibility().zIndex === "0"
                    ) {
                        panel.setIssue(currentIssueSelected);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        button3.removeClass("top_view_selected");
        button3.addClass("top_view");
        button3.setToolTip("Mostrar planta");

        var issues_combo_button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ComboButton(
            "issues_combo_button"
        );
        issues_combo_button.setIcon("issues_combo_button");

        issues_combo_button.onMouseOver = function (e) {
            issues_combo_button.setIcon("issues_combo_button_selected");
        };
        issues_combo_button.onMouseOut = function (e) {
            issues_combo_button.setIcon("issues_combo_button");
        };
        var utils_combo_button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ComboButton(
            "utils_combo_button"
        );
        utils_combo_button.setIcon("utils_combo_button");

        utils_combo_button.onMouseOver = function (e) {
            utils_combo_button.setIcon("utils_combo_button_selected");
        };
        utils_combo_button.onMouseOut = function (e) {
            utils_combo_button.setIcon("utils_combo_button");
        };

        this.subToolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup(
            "my-custom-toolbar"
        );
        this.subToolbar2 = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup(
            "my-custom-toolbar2"
        );
        if (mainViewer.model.is3d()) {
            utils_combo_button.addControl(button3);
        }
        this.subToolbar.addControl(issues_combo_button);
        // SubToolbar
        toolbar.addControl(this.subToolbar);
        if (mainViewer.model.is3d()) {
            this.subToolbar2.addControl(utils_combo_button);
            toolbar.addControl(this.subToolbar2);
        }
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
        "ToolbarExtension",
        ToolbarExtension
    );
};

const handleViewerWidth = () => {
    //...
};

return (
    <div
        style={{
            width: handleViewerWidth(),
            height: "100%",
            position: "absolute",
            left: `${
                isTreeActive || isIssuesListActive || isBlueprintsListActive
                    ? "23%"
                    : "3%"
            }`,
        }}
        id="mainViewerDiv"
    />
)}
```

In the above example you can see that I use the context variable `currentIssueSelected` inside button3 onClick and it's always undefined, what I already tried:

1. Receive the currentIssueValue by a props in viewer component function `Viewer({currentIssueSel}){...}`;
2. Make a global function and assign it to the onClick;

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unrelated but why are you using function and prototype to create classes?  Second, this is too much code for us to examine. You should remove all the code that is not required to reproduce the problem.See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*May be this issue is related to the timing of when the onClick function is defined and executed so you can try to use useEffect hook to update the onClick function whenever the context values change.The useEffect with currentIssueSelected in its dependency array ensures that the onClick function is updated whenever currentIssueSelected changes.*

```
 const [button3ClickHandler, setButton3ClickHandler] = useState(() => {});

  useEffect(() => {
    setButton3ClickHandler(() => {
      return function (e) {
        console.log("CURRENT ISSUE SELECTED", currentIssueSelected);
        if (!currentIssueSelected) {
          showErrorToasty(
            "Não é possível ver planta sem um problema selecionado"
          );
        } else {
          // ... rest of your onClick logic ...
        }
      };
    });
  }, [currentIssueSelected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const auxinitViewer = async () => {
      setMainViewer(await initViewer(document.getElementById("mainViewerDiv")));
    };
    initExtensions();
    auxinitViewer();
  }, [currentIssueSelected]);

  const initExtensions = async () => {
    // ... your existing code ...

    button3.onClick = button3ClickHandler;

    // ... rest of your onToolbarCreated logic ...
  };
```

Comment: It works man, thanks so mutch